# Installing rosclj

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am at beginner level in ROS.

I am trying to explore hierarchical_planning ([www.ros.org/wiki/hierarchical_planning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hierarchical_planning)) and thus needed to install rosjava and rosclj,

I was able to install rosjava quite easily using http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html

but couldn't figure out how to install rosclj. (from http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosclj). Looks very silly, please help.

It seems that http://ros.berkeley.edu/svn/berkeley-ros-pkg/stacks/clj_planning/trunk/clj_planning/rosclj is temporarily down,  or is there any other issue? I guess I will download it from here only.

Also

I followed http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosclj and installed Clojure from synaptic, should I set CLJ_HOME to point to /usr/share/java, or should I copy relevent jars from /usr/share/java to a folder and point CLJ_HOME over there?

In the tutorial immediately after this (in section 2.1 Creating, building, and running rosclj packages) instructions are there to add rosclj package in a newly created package.

Kindly also tell me what should be the right sequence of tutorial etc to be read so that I be able to (in simulation) :-
navigate avoiding obstacle,
and then,
pick and place objects from one point to other.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33654/installing-rosclj/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-05-09**:
I am using ros-electric on ubuntu 11.10 , 64 bit (guess thats not relevant here)

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-05-10**:
Of course, svn co http://ros.berkeley.edu/svn/berkeley-ros-pkg/stacks/clj_planning/trunk/clj_planning/rosclj
gives o/p : svn: OPTIONS of 'http://ros.berkeley.edu/svn/berkeley-ros-pkg/stacks/clj_planning/trunk/clj_planning/rosclj': 200 OK (http://ros.berkeley.edu)
also if I try to open it in browser

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-05-10**:
I get 404 Not found, in fact link : http://ros.berkeley.edu/svn/ itself does not exist.May be its moved to somewhere else. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wow. You found a really old package. I'm actually not sure if ROS' Clojure support is still maintained and it looks like it has never been ported to Google's new rosjava. I guess berkley-ros-pkg is down because it doesn't exist anymore.

Since rosclj is pretty old, probably not maintained anymore and incompatible with the rosjava version you installed, I don't think it's a good idea to still try to use it unless you want to invest a lot of time porting it. You might be able to find the rosclj sources in an old revision of one of Willow Garage's ROS repositories if you really want to try.

As far as I know, rosclj was just a wrapper around rosjava plus a few utility functions to control the robot. Not that much code I think. If you want to use Clojure together with ROS and it should be fairly simple to use Java libraries in Clojure, you should be able to communicate through ROS without rosclj but by just using Clojure and the new rosjava. TF integration and an action client library are still not finished, but will come in the near future.

If you want to use ROS together with Common Lisp, you can use [roslisp](http://ros.org/wiki/roslisp). It is still maintained and we provide a native implementation of [tf](http://ros.org/wiki/cl_tf) and [actionlib](http://ros.org/wiki/actionlib_lisp).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0